# {grape} authorization

Tags: ruby, api, authorization, grape-api

I'm attempting to create a restful, json api in ruby - so I'm using grape (https://github.com/intridea/grape) inside of Rack.
I'm not using Rails for this project, so cancan, sorcery, etc... don't seem to be the best options. Plus, I'd hate to mix in a bunch of imperative logic into grape's declarative DSL.

While grape has built in authentication support, I do not see anything about authorization. It seems like this would be a common enough use case that this road would have been traveled before, but after some pretty thorough digging in google and the grape codebase itself I have turned up nothing.

Has anyone implemented something like this for their project in grape? What did you use?

Answer (score 8):

This may be a little too late, but anyway. I'd recommend you use *Pundit* for authorization, it's deadly simple. To use it in your *Grape* API endpoints, you would need to include Pundit helpers:

```
class API < Grape::API
  format :json

  helpers Pundit
  helpers do
    def current_user
      resource_owner
    end
  end

  mount FoosAPI
end
```

Now in you API endpoints, you should be able to use `authorize foo, action?` as you would always do in Rails controllers:

```
class FoosAPI < Grape::API
  get ':id' do
    foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
    authorize foo, :show?
    present foo, with: FooEntity
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hey bud thanks, just one thing the second param of the authorize method is actually a symbol
`authorize :foo, :show?`

The first param can be a symbol, name of the class or an instance of the class

Comment: @JGonzalezD: Nice catch, fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I can give short comment on this, but the field is to short, sorry if it will not be right answer but:

You mentioned sorcery - I think it is authentication system and got nothing to do with an authorization. (I do not know sorcery gem implementation - just repeating statement from documentation and assuming that description enumerates such systems it replaces and it is valid definition). I guess it is just mistake.

Fundamental question you should ask yourself is...

How much role-based system do you develop? I think if this is only matter of public/private/admin roles probably you should consider just moving it to different APIs.

That can be cumbersome in some circumstances but worth a try for not complicated none additive roles. Simple mount in grape will solve the problem OOTB.

Real problem is if you think about some expandable/dynamic role system or you want to be just DRY. That can be painful ;-). I think Rayan's Bytes cancan gem implementation should help you understand how such problem can be solved on higher abstract level. For particular (without higher abstraction - such as dynamic roles) implementation it should be fine to just use currently given helpers from grape and delegate their responsibilities to model (basic usage).

```
helpers do
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.authorize!(env)
  end

  def authenticate!
    error!('401 Unauthorized', 401) unless current_user
  end
end
```

so all the story is about how to implement User.authorize!(env) and I believe that should be done in your model and depends strictly on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my answer is in time for you. I recently have the same problem with the **Grape** and **authorization** in a Rails4 project. And after trying, I found out a way for this.
In my project, I'm using the [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for **authorization**, it asks me to create a **policy** folder, and create the authorize rules for each Model, each rule is a Ruby class, something like this(from pundit Github page)

```
class PostPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  def update?
    user.admin? or not record.published?
  end
end
```

then in the Grape API, I just use this class for the authorization, code like this:

```
desc "hide a post"
post :hide do
  authenticate!
  error!( "user unauthorized for this" ) unless PostPolicy.new(current_user, @post).hide_post?
  @post.update hidden: true
  { hidden: @post.hidden }
end
```

the `authenticate!` and `current_user` helpers are customized helpers. By this way, I can reuse the authorize rules created when developing website parts.

This works for me. Hope the **Pundit** way can solve your problems for **Grape authorization**